# AWS Cognito Identity Pool: AWS Credentials Expiration / Renewal

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm building an AWS-backed site which, broadly speaking, does the following:

1. Authenticates a user against a Cognito User Pool (the pool is backed by a third-party SAML provider), giving them tokens.
2. Uses a Cognito Identity Pool to grant the user credentials for use with other services.
3. Lets the user perform a series of long-running S3 uploads, directly from the front-end S3 client, using the credentials from above.

I'm trying to get clarity on the interactions I will have to have with tokens and credentials. I'm pretty clear on what I have to do with [the tokens I get from the user pool](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html):

1. I can use them to call the Identity Pool, and get AWS credentials I can use for S3.
2. I can use the refresh token to refresh the other tokens if they expire before I'm done.

The expiration details for these tokens are in the link above. The documentation is pretty clear on all of the above, but I'm confused about the Identity Pool credential functionality, and haven't been able to find explanations in the docs on the following questions:

1. When I get AWS credentials from my Identity Pool, how long will they last before expiring? How can I configure this value, so that my [`CognitoIdentityCredentials`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html) gives me credentials with my desired expiration?
2. If my AWS credentials expire before I'm done with my work, what's the right logic for attempting to 1. refresh the credentials and 2. if that fails, refresh the user pool tokens, so as to be able to complete the operation cleanly without making the user restart it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user pool is only for user management. Any interaction that the user has with AWS services and resources is done via Identity Pool. You assign the roles via Identity pool.
To answer your 2 specific questions:

1. Tokens last for 1 hour. This duration is fixed and cannot be changed.
2. If your tokens expire you can use the refresh token to generate new identity and access tokens. However, most of the front end sdks (even javascript) do this automatically for you. You don't have to worry about tokens expiring. In fact you will have to forcefully invalidate them if you have that requirement.

Comment: For my knowledge, isn't it unsafe to have a refresh token on the browser based application

Comment: @ArunK Yes it isn't considered good practice. The best way of doing this is to use Authorization code grant and not sending any tokens to front end at all. The Amplify library for front end can handle authorization code grant as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response - on point #1: does the 1hr apply to both user pool auth tokens and id pool aws tokens? And on point #2: does this auto refresh include both user pool auth tokens, and id pool aws tokens? What happens if I have a multipart upload that takes more than 1hr?

Comment: Yes both auth and id token have 1 hour validity. Refresh token has more and you can control how long it lasts. As for auto refresh, the token is refreshed before making any calls with them by using the session object so you won't ever face any token expired issues even with multipart upload.

Comment: You can now edit the id and access token expiry times, it's set it the user pool client.